# not able to add one string and file to FormData in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot

in my case , i need to add one file and one String value to formData. File Value is appending but string value is not appending

```
const uploadClickHandler=()=>
      {
       
        const formData = new FormData();
       
        for(let i = 0; i< files.length; i++) {
          formData.append('file', files[i])
        }
        formData.append('name','ajith')
     
        console.log(formData);
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/hello/',formData,{
          headers: {
            "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"
          }
        })
```

In server Side, only file is coming, not string value.

```
@PostMapping(value="/hello", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ArrayList<LoadDirectoryResponse> getFile(@RequestPart(value="file") MultipartFile[] files)
{
    System.out.println(files.length);
    ArrayList<LoadDirectoryResponse> dirlist = new ArrayList<LoadDirectoryResponse>();
    
    for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
    {
        LoadDirectoryResponse obj = new LoadDirectoryResponse(files[i].getOriginalFilename());
        dirlist.add(obj);
    }
    return dirlist;
```

it printing length as 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed something

```
public ArrayList<LoadDirectoryResponse> getFile(@RequestPart(value="file") MultipartFile[] files,@RequestPart(value="name") String name)
```

here the name is your string at server side
you are creating custom form in client side then there are no orgin name for that form you also need to acess name from the requeste part

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass that string value with body

```
const uploadClickHandler=()=>
  {
   
    const formData = new FormData();
   
    for(let i = 0; i< files.length; i++) {
      formData.append('file', files[i])
    }
    formData.append('name','ajith')
 
    console.log(formData);
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/hello/',formData,{
      headers: {
        "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"
      },
      body:{
       name:formData.name
        }
    })
```

Comment: how can i handle this at server side

Answer (score -1):

Convert it into a string with JSON.stringify()

```
const formData = JSON.stringify(formData);
```

and when pulling back the data use JSON.parse()

```
const formData = JSON.parse(formData);
```